# Sejda-console split by text : set the output file name to the changed value?

Tags: sejda

I'm looking to use Sejda to burst a PDF file with payslips into individual payslip files. The ***split by text*** option perfectly splits the files per employee number (changing value on the page).

I would like to include this changing value in the output filenames, so I can identify the payslips for each employee.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `[TEXT]` prefix which is part of the [output prefix](http://www.sejda.org/development/the-outputprefix-option/) functionality in Sejda. It is not in the documentation yet because version 2 of Sejda is still under development and subject to change.

So if you add link `-p [TEXT]` that should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

### Summary

The `[TEXT]` prefix allows the file to be named according to the text used to `splitbytext`.

### Example

The flag `-p [TEXT]` successfully named the output documents for a number of my projects. The following is an example of a successful `splitbytext` extraction performed in Windows:

`sejda-console splitbytext -f input.pdf --top 514 --left 61 --width 75 --height 22 -p [TEXT] -o .\outdirectory`

FYI The text I was using to split the document was in the rectangle that began at points coordinates (x,y)=(514,61) [sic].

Thanks to Andrea Vacondio for their answer.